# Binary String Converted to Integers

Tags: c++, indexing

Trying to convert a string of binary inputs into a vector of ints. I'd like to do this without using a built-in C++ function. Here is a snippet of the code and the execution errors (compiles fine).

Example Input: "1011 1001 1101"

Should be stored in vector as ints 11,9, and 13

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()  
{
    string code,key;
    vector<int>digcode;
    vector<int>ans;
    cout<<"Enter binary code:\n";
    getline(cin,code);
    cout<<"Enter secret key:\n";
    cin>>key;

    for(int i=0;i<code.length();)
    {
        int j=2, num=0;
        while (code[i]!=' '&&i<code.length())
        {
        num*=j;
        if (code[i]=='1')
        num+=1;
            i++;
        }
        cout<<num<<" ";
        digcode.push_back(num);
        if(code[i]==' '&&i<code.length())
            i++;
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE: "Debug Assertion Failed!" "Expression: string subscript out of range"

All but the last number are printed and stored. I've traced through the for and while loops looking for where the subscript gets too large, but haven't had much luck.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the assertion tell you which line the error happens on? If you have that information why are you keeping it secret? It's the most important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: You could check out `strtol` if you aren't against using C functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operands are in the wrong order:

```
while (code[i]!=' '&&i<code.length())
```

change to:

```
while (i < code.length() && code[i]!=' ')
```

Same for following `if` statement. The second operand will only be evaluated if the first operand is true, preventing out of bounds access.

Comment: excellent, i wasn't considering the ordering of the conditions. thanks! it's now printing and storing all the entered numbers, but still printing out the same error.

Comment: @NicholasNickleby, did you change the `if` operand order also?

Answer (score 0):

After you parse the digits by space? 
There is the `strtol()` function that you can supply a base conversion to and get the integer value.

[See it here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be simplified a fair bit:

```
for (std::string line; ; )
{
    std::cout << "Enter a line: ";
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) { break; }

    for (std::string::const_iterator it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); )
    {
        unsigned int n = 0;
        for ( ; it != line.end() && *it == ' '; ++it) { }
        // maybe check that *it is one of { '0', '1', ' ' }

        for ( ; it != line.end() && *it != ' '; ++it) { n *= 2; n += (*it - '0'); }
        std::cout << "   Read one number: " << n << std::endl;
    }
}
```